# Is there a simple way to just insert a link to an image (without inserting an image)?

Tags: images, links

**UPDATE 2018**: The plugin listed below no longer works with WP (as of version 4.5 I believe) but the code listed in the accepted answer DOES still work, so use that instead.

UPDATE: just found this plugin which does what I wanted and more: https://wordpress.org/plugins/b09-link-to-existing-content/faq

I'm pulling my hair out with this, it seems so simple, but there is no easy way in WP (that I can find), and no plugin that will do the following:

In a post, I want to select some text, and then add a link to an existing (full size) image in my media library. I DON'T want to insert an image into my post.

The only way I have found to be able to do this is to find the image, copy the file link, then go to insert/edit url and paste it in. There should be a way to find it the same way you find pages or posts to link to in that same dialog. (OR maybe there is, and I simply can't find it because I am an idiot.)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without a plugin. I do it the same way you do. Find the image first, copy the image url, and add to the link.

Comment: Do you know of any plugin that does this? I have scoured the plugin db but haven't found anything that extends that insert/edit dialog (which I guess would be the best way to do it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution based on the code of this page:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22180

All attachment files have a post status of 'inherit'. So first you need to add "inherit" as one of the possible post status to search for. You can use the wp_link_query_args filter to do that.

```
function my_wp_link_query_args( $query ) {

     if (is_admin()){
          $query['post_status'] = array('publish','inherit');
     }

     return $query;

}

add_filter('wp_link_query_args', 'my_wp_link_query_args');
```

By default the url you would get would be the attachment url, and not the file url. So if you need the file url you can use the filter wp_link_query to filter the results.

```
function my_modify_link_query_results( $results, $query ) {

  foreach ($results as &$result ) {
    if ('Media' === $result['info']) {
      $result['permalink'] = wp_get_attachment_url($result['ID']);
    }
  }

  return $results;

}

add_filter('wp_link_query', 'my_modify_link_query_results', 10, 2);
```

The foreach loops through all results, find the ones that have a type of Media, and replaces the attachment URL with the file url.

Comment: I think this is more slick +1 than my solution (even though they're using same hooks) so I've deleted mine to favor yours ;-) Good findings!

Comment: @birgire I started writing my answer, and only saw yours after I published mine. Thanks!

Comment: btw, I think this is worth turning into a plugin for other people. Let me know if you want to do it and if not, I can create the plugin and upload it to the repo. Thanks again!

Comment: Feel free to do it.

Comment: FYI, just found this plugin which does what I wanted and more: https://wordpress.org/plugins/b09-link-to-existing-content/faq/

Comment: In [a suggested edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/232032) @iiic points out that the 'Media' string in the wp_link_query handler does get localised and so isn't a good idea to test against. I think you ought to test `get_post_type( $result['ID'] ) === 'attachment'` instead. And probably break when you find one too, unless you particularly want the last match where multiple.